# In typescript, how to declare a function before its use - C style

Tags: typescript

I have a function which is for instance

```
function init(model: any, eventData: UserApplicationModel) : any
```

I would like to avoid having to mix the type information with the function source code. I tried (in the same source file):

```
declare function init(model: any, eventData: UserApplicationModel) : any;
function init(model, eventData) {
  // source code here
}
```

but I get `error TS2384: Overload signatures must all be ambient or non-ambient`.

My question is, is it possible at all to pre-declare a function, so one does not have to repeat the type information? That would be great, adding type information at the same type at defining the function makes for very long lines in some cases.

---

Comment: What about using d.ts files?

Comment: If there is no other way, then yes, but everytime I modify my function's signature I will have to jump to that file to update it. Might as well just keep declaring the signature directly in the function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can define a function signature using a `type`, such as:

```
type init = (model: any, eventData: UserApplicationModel) => any;
```

Then initialize it later, by assigning an anonymous function expression to a variable of that type:

```
var init: init = function (model, eventData) {
    ...
};
```

This will give you full type-safety even inside the function body. This could be useful when blindly transpiling C code to TypeScript.

Comment: interesting. I would however very muck like to maintain the IDE support I get through the type declaration though. If `eventData` is recognized as any, then I loose that.

Comment: @user3743222 -- As it turns out, there is _indeed_ a way to accomplish what you are looking for, I've updated the answer accordingly. I'm not sure why I didn't think about this earlier.

Comment: thanks john, that is pretty close. I think that is probably the closest one can get. Damn typescript

Answer (score 0):

```
function init(model: any, eventData: UserApplicationModel) : any;
function init(model, eventData) {
    // source code here
}
```

Will do the trick. Note the omission of the `declare` modifier.
For this to work, the type signature needs to be directly above the corresponding implementation as shown. You can create multiple overloads of an implementation in this fashion.
In any case, the actual implementation's type signature will be conveniently masked by the function signature above it.

**Update**

I believe that I may have misunderstood the question. This will provide a typed function signature for callers to consume but will not implicitely provide types for the parameters and return type of the implementation. The implementation will only be constrained to have argument types, argument arity, and a return type that conform to the overload signature above it.

Comment: Which version of typescript are you using? With which compiler options? I get something similar to @john Weisz, i.e. that `model` and `eventData` have the any type, hence I actually loose the typing information by declaring before as you suggest. PS: I use ts2.1.4 with `"noImplicitAny": true`

Comment: Because I didn't specify them in the implementation but that won't affect the caller. The caller will see the overload above. You are free to specificy the types in your implementation as well. I'm using the latest 2.2.0-dev, but this has worked since many releases ago.

Answer (score 0):

This is not the answer you're looking for, but I'd suggest you don't try to do this. There are several arguments for this:

- It goes against the intentions of the language designers. All the documentation for proper TypeScript uses the form where argument types are specified with the function body.
- Tied to this, most production code follows this pattern. If you ever plan on open sourcing this, it is going to work against the product. Similarly, any other internal devs are going to find it hard to follow.
- It makes the code harder to follow. Type info is in one place, code is in another. When you want to do a modification, you need to do it in two places.
- It opens you up for bugs. TypeScript has function overloading. Perhaps you modify the args list in one place but not the other, the compiler doesn't mind and you get a runtime error. Defeats the purpose of the type system.
- It looks like C/C++. There are historical reasons why those languages have declaration and definition files. But no other modern-ish language has copied the "feature". It stems from a limitation in earlier compilers and computers and it's a hassle to deal with.

If you find you have too many arguments, there are other solutions. You can pack them into an object, for example. You could use the builder pattern for it. You could group the functions into an object, and provide all the arguments at construction time, and have each object operate on the fields.

Comment: I was in fact thinking about haskell : `add                     :: Integer -> Integer -> Integer`, 
`add x y                 =  x + y`. There is no big drama there, though the type inference is good enough that you dont have too often to declare your types yourself. Unfortunately that is not the case for the typescript, and you need to type way too often.

Comment: @user3743222 oh yes, I forgot that Haskell also does this of the more "well known" programming languages. It bothered me in Haskell as well, though I guess they're kind of _forced_ to do it, so they have a nice syntax for pattern matching.

Comment: Cant tell if they were *forced* to do it, but it was definitely smart to do it. Given that changing the place of declaration of types preserve semantics, why would want to do one or the other? There are miscellaneous reasons, you mentioned a few for the older languages. In my case it is simply readability. It is painful to read through code where the type information in interlaced with the instructions flow. Different people will be affected differently but it impacts my productivity (negatively).